# Will the latest Ubuntu fit on a 700 MB CD?

Tags: installation, macbook, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install the non-CD size 12.04 on a computer that can't boot from USB & can't read DVD-Rs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76874/how-can-i-install-the-non-cd-size-12-04-on-a-computer-that-cant-boot-from-usb)
>   [Will 12.04 image fit on one 700 MB CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179161/will-12-04-image-fit-on-one-700-mb-cd)

Will it fit on a regular 700 MB CD?

Also, I have a macbook that currently has an erased HD (so no OS installed currently) if i boot from a CD can I choose to allocate my whole HD to Ubuntu?

Also the old OS my macbook was running on was 64 bit, should i also use Ubuntu 64 bit as well?

Thanks :)

Comment: By latest, do you mean 12.04.1 or 12.10?

Comment: [Possible](http://askubuntu.com/q/76874/12864) [Duplicates](http://askubuntu.com/q/179161/12864)?

Answer (score 0):

The installation CD's for the latest stable release (12.04) will fit on a 700 MB CD-ROM. The daily images for the test version 12.10 might be larger.

As for 32bit vs 64bit. You can use both Ubuntu versions, in general there will be no huge disadvantage (and maybe even an advantage) to use the 32b version. Read more [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit).