# Is there a latest version of Ubuntu less than 700MB?

Tags: system-installation, cd

I want to install the lastest version of ubuntu (14.04) on my old windows PC but it only has a CD-ROM drive, and the BIOS is not letting me install from much else, so I want to find a ISO that is less than 700MB to fit on a CD-R. Is there one? The regular one that I downloaded is over 900MB.

Comment: See http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install the non-CD size 12.04 on a computer that can't boot from USB & can't read DVD-Rs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76874/how-can-i-install-the-non-cd-size-12-04-on-a-computer-that-cant-boot-from-usb)

Comment: @EricCarvalho, not a duplicate since this is about 14.04

Comment: @psusi How does this affect the content of the question and answer?

Comment: @LiveWireBT, nevermind.. I only read the first part of the answer where it said that in the end, 12.04 did fit on a cd and didn't see the mention of the mini iso.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using Minimal CD. You can find it here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

It doesn't contain all the packages but downloads them during install time. Of course you will have to be online during installing time and preferably have decent Internet speed.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" 31MB. To someone trying to install from CD (like me) it could have been closer to 700 MB. There isn't a medium-ISO somewhere?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization I just found this place where I was able to download a 800mb

Answer (score 1):

Go over to the Lubuntu download [site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu), download the correct version (i guess 32-bit), and burn it to an CD. Just follow the installation to install Lubuntu, and after you are in your new system, do the following steps to remove all of the Lubuntu specific software, and install the Ubuntu equivalents;

1. Open a terminal, be sure you have Internet, then type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
2. When this is finished type  `lightdm-set-defaults -g unity-greeter` (This will change your automatic login to the new desktop)
3. Reboot, and when in your new Ubuntu desktop, open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get remove --purge lubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

But because your system already is a bit older (i made this assumption based on the fact that it doesn't support USB booting), it may be better to keep Lubuntu, because it's more resource friendly. And the only difference between the two are the looks, Ubuntu uses Unity and Lubuntu uses LXDE, and the set of "base" software that comes with it such as the terminal, notepad, music player etc.

If you chose to use Lubuntu, you may also want to check out the other Ubuntu based distributions over at [Ubuntu Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Recognised%20Flavors) . Which all follow the same principal as mentioned before.