# How to recover deleted partitions on computer that doesn't boot up

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery, usb-drive

I can't boot up Ubuntu from a USB 2.0 drive.

I burned Ubuntu 18.04, but I do not seem able to initialize it: I obtain `(initramfs Unable to find a medium containing a live file system`. I checked [other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76874/how-can-i-install-the-non-cd-size-12-04-on-a-computer-that-cant-boot-from-usb/78801?newreg=ef201e375c4f4275a185141e2cca2ae0), but I do not seem to be able to run Ubuntu.
EDIT: nomodoset does not seem to work.

[The errors shown at startup are here](https://gyazo.com/fb1e635f13c71c5cd555370d4c4338d9)

Please help me out with this.

EDIT:
Using Ubuntu 18.04, and `nomodeset` does not work. Using Ubuntu 19.10, with the safe graphics or `nomodeset` option does not work too.

EDIT 2: Problem solved. As pointed out in the comments, check the image with `md5sum`, and use a default tool, such as Ubuntu's Disk Creator to create the USB boot drive.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1217381/925971 enable nomodeset before booting

Comment: @Gryu I've tried to do so, by adding ``nomodoset``, after ``quiet splash``, but it still doesn't work. I no longer get the ``Unable to find a medium containing a live file system``, but I do get other errors. I've also tried the safe graphics option from the Ubuntu 19.10 image

Comment: SAFEST method probably would be: Take the disk out of the system. Buy a new disk. Install Ubuntu on that. Then run a recover program over the mounted partitions.

Comment: You don't say that you've enabled in your BIOS your USB drive as the default boot disk. Have you done that?

Comment: Maybe there was a typing error. The boot option must be `nomodeset` with 2 o's and 2 e's, not as you wrote 3 o's and one e.

Comment: Thank for all your inputs, I really appreciate that.
Although the safest method would be taking the disk out, I have a laptop, and that process may be cumbersome, so I was trying to avoid that, if possible.

Boot mode is UEFI, fast boot disabled, PXE Boot to LAN enabled, IPV4 PXE First disabled, USB drive before EFI PXE Network. 
Adding ``nomodeset`` right before the three dashes still yields the errors. I'll paste the errors in the post.

Comment: Please tell us about the computer: Brand name and model. I understand from the picture of the screen with 'nouveau' that there is a problem with the nvidia graphics. Maybe there is another problem too. So it is also good for us to know the version of your nvidia chip/card. It might help to try a newer version of Ubuntu that brings a newer version of the graphics driver, so try 19.10 or the developing version Focal Fossa, to be released in April as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: 1. Did you check with `md5sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly? 2. Which tool did you use to create the USB boot drive? 3. Did you check from the boot menu, that all software on the USB boot drive is correctly copied? 4. And please tell us about the computer and graphics chip/card: Brand name and model ... otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @sudodus, thank you :) It was the way I was creating the USB boot drive. I used the default ubuntu Disk Creator, and it was fine.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved the problem and thanks for sharing your solution :-)