# Help installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation

Downloaded and burnt Ubuntu Linux 11.10 Installation on DVD. Have new IDE hard drive to install it on. Computer System Information:
Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz
Speed 2500MHz
Count 2
Installed & Useable size system memory: 2048MB
Updated the Bios:
Version: 0603
Build Date: 08/20/10

Every time I try and boot using the installation DVD I get the message: "(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". Tried changing many different options in BIOS.
Seen a lot of people with a similar problem change the SATA configuration from IDE to AHCI but I don't have the option of choosing AHCI.

Will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: maybe there's an error on the burned dvd ... check de md5checksum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Did you choose the 'write iso' mod when creating the DVD instead of create 'data dvd'?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 5):

(**Answered by OP in comments**)

> Had burnt and tried two DVDs but found place on internet where they'd suggested using [`UNetBootin`](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a USB stick and tried and worked! Finally!