# (initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system Toshiba

Tags: system-installation, 10.04

When I try to boot from my USB it says:

> (initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system

How can I install Ubuntu 10.04 on my Toshiba Satellite Pro C650?

Additional details:

- My USB is 2.0
- I changed all possible settings in BIOS. (e.g. AHCI)
- ISO is not corrupted (boot is successful on my other HP Laptop)
- XUbuntu works

Comment: How did you install the usb image? was it an ISO written with the Ubuntu startup disc creator? Did you create it on windows or Linux?

Please post the file format of the image you downloaded (.img or .iso) and the software used to write the USB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Comment: If we are going to remove old obsolete duplicate questions and answers, then we should remove all old obsolete duplicate questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try a newer release.  This problem, bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/817145 was present for me in 12.04, but not in 13.04.