# Ubuntu 12.10 Install Issues

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-cd, initramfs

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a x86 Sony VAIO (its 10 years old.. running XP) and it is not working at all. I burned a LiveCD, popped it in, it came up to the Ubuntu splash screen then came to this:

```
BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.19.3-7Ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initrams) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
_
```

After a little research, I tried the CD on a x64 machine to find it works perfectly (the LiveCD is the x32 version), a laptop about 2 years old. I have tried unplugging unnecessary USB devices, there is no IDE > AHCI option in BIOS.. and I know my CD drive should be OK, I've done LiveCD's before. Anyone have any ideas? Make enter a special code by pressing Shift at the disc startup? Any help here is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Anyone have anything? Please? :'-

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using the alternative installed which is text based.  That seems to work

Comment: Thank you for your Response! I am a newbie to linux, how do you get/get into the text based installer?

Comment: um, yeah, alternate cd's for Ubuntu were dropped for 12.10, http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Drops-Alternate-CDs-from-Ubuntu-12-10-289338.shtml

Comment: naw man that is a :(