# ubuntu 12.10, 12.04 "Unable to find medium containing a live file system"

Tags: installation, 12.10, xen

When installing ubuntu via xen i get 

`Unable to find medium containing a live file system`

i go the iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

and have been following this tuorial

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed : Manually installing an HVM Guest VM

this is my xen cfg file

```
builder='hvm'
kernel='/usr/lib/xen-4.1/boot/hvmloader'
name = "ubuntu"
memory = "2048"
maxmem = "13312"
vcpus = 4
disk = ['phy:/dev/server/ubuntu-hvm,hda,w','file:/data/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-     amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
vfb = ["type=vnc, vncunused=1, keymap=en-us, vnclisten=0.0.0.0"]
vif = ['bridge=eth0']
boot="dc"
device_model='/usr/lib/xen-4.1/qemu-dm'
```

i tested 12.04, 11.10 ange get the same error

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/15425/40581

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a guesswork:

1. The space at 'file:/data/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-     amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r' shouldn't be there. If you copy/pasted your config file, you need to fix that.
2. Check device_model='/usr/lib/xen-4.1/qemu-dm' to see if qemu-dm is in fact there. In my (Ubuntu-based) Linux Mint 13 distro it's /usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/qemu-dm
3. disk = ['phy:/dev/server/ubuntu-hvm,hda,w' seems to specify a regular disk, not a LVM volume. It shouldn't cause a problem, but I believe the partition (or LVM volume) needs to be unformatted.
4. Don't know if it's related, but vif = ['bridge=eth0'] looks strange. Is eth0 your bridge? Anyway this is the last thing I would check, after everything else fails.
5. You may want to try virt-manager (a GUI, you need to install libvirt and perhaps some more packages). Make sure you uncomment the

   ```
          (xend-unix-server yes)
   ```

   line in /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp