# Unable to find a medium containing a live file system with boot from iso

Tags: boot, system, iso

Unable to find a medium containing a live file system:

```
 reset/press Shift/c (command line)
 grub> insmod iso9660
 grub> loopback l (hd0,6)/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso
 grub> set root=(l)
 grub> source (l)/boot/grub/loopback.cfg
 grub> [press Esc]
 Select Install Lubuntu
 ......
 (initramfs)Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
 (initramfs)
```

Comment: Please describe a bit more about your current setup; hardware, other Linux ISOs tried, boot from USB, etc. It looks like the storage controller isn't working as it can't find the CDROM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Answer (score 3):

Resolved as:

```
set iso_path=/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso
```