# Which version of Ubuntu is recommened for Samsung NB R519

Tags: system-installation

While I use USB stick with ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso for Samsung NB R519. after it runs a while, the installation stopped with an error message "(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Does this NB not suitable to install Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: It sounds to me as though your computer stops recognising the USB port, midway through the installation. If it starts installing, it should work OK. I'm not sure, but perhaps you could make sure that there are no power saving features turned on... but there again, I could be totally wrong!

Comment: Try This.  Go into the BIOS, and change SATA Settings,  use AHCI instead of IDE.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 1):

Burn your iso image of ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop and then try installing ubuntu by booting from the CD. If you have any doubt in installing via CD reffer installing [ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)