# Booting from SD

Tags: boot, hp, sd-card

Attempting to boot from a 16GB SDHC card on an HP ProBook 4530s. Used universal USB installer (pendrive) supplied via link from ubuntu.com to create the bootable drive. In the start up menu, I choose the SD card as the boot device, it starts, shows some script, shows the Ubuntu installing screen for a lengthy while, back to script then 
"Unable to find medium containing live file stream"

Comp is currently running Win7 prof 64bit
Trying to load ubuntu 13.04 amd64.

Not sure if this matters, but it cant hurt:
i5 quad core 2.3ghz
8GB ddr3
intel HD graphics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the boot-able image created is faulty.

**Format your SD card :** 
Your windows might not format the SD card properly. Use the software from SD
[SD Formatter 4.0 for Windows Download](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/)

Download a fresh copy of the Ubuntu .iso and then use below tool for windows to create a **bootable card** using [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

Should work after this. :)

Comment: No good, I followed these instructions precisely and still received the error. Any other ideas that might help me out?

Comment: It looks a tad different, though. Before, when the error reared its ugly head there was a whole mess of script I didnt understand leading up to the error. Now, it displays only
-BusyBox v1.20.2 (ubuntu 1:1.20.0 -8ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
-Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
-(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Comment: There may be a problem with the USB port in which you are plugging your drive into. If it is a USB 3.0 try using one  which is USB 2.0. Here is a link to similar problem faced by some-other people                                                              [click here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Comment: It is not a USB port, it is an integrated SDHC slot on the laptop.
Aside from that my computer does not have a USB 3.0 port. Regardless, when attempting to create a bootable USB, I tried every port and came to the same issue.

Comment: I would suggest you use a external card reader if you can borrow it from someone and try it once, i am pretty sure there is some issue with the card reader compatibility with your SD card. Maby try a flashdrive instead of the SDHC.