# booting from USB stick

Tags: usb, live-usb

I have created a bootable USB stick (USB2/4GB) using the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. Using 12.0.4 on 32bit laptop.

All seems to work, no errors. But when I then boot from this on a laptop, I get the Ubuntu logo, lots of output and then errors such as

```
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
device not accepting address , error -110
```

and finally
unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
After this I can press enter and get a initramfs shell.
I can then shutdown using a long press on power button. The shutdown command is not part of this shell.

So I am guessing that the stick is working otherwise I would not get this far though there may be corruption in the files(?). No other usb ports being used though touchpad/keyboard may be usb.

I have googled this and the only answer seems to be shutting down, removing the power cord (and in my case the battery) for 5 minutes and trying again. This has not worked.

I did get this working a few years back with the same USB stick (since reformatted) on a different laptop. This laptop is a thinkpad T61.
Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Just to add the first line of output where it starts to go wrong is `[initramfs] Unable to find a medium containing a live file system`

Just compared checksum with what I downloaded and they are the same. I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso

Regards,
John

Comment: Just to add the first line of output where it starts to go wrong is [initramfs] Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Comment: Just compared checksum with what I downloaded and they are the same. I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: Try another brand of USB stick? I've had problems in the past. Also try an alternative installer (the program that preps USB.)

Comment: @John I edited your question to include your comments in the question(as well as added code blocks to your errors so they wer easier to read/find). If you need to add any info to your questions(or any answers you may make in the future) just click  `edit` just below your question then click save rather than use comments.  sorry I am not able to help you with an answer, I'm not sure what is going on here. you can delete your comment by clicking the `X` next to them to keep the question clean.

Comment: Hi fleamour, I tried with a new installer (UNetbootin) and though far less oitput it hands at the "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system" stage. I do not think it is the installer as such as it does boot from the USB. I noticed a similar problem on this forum where every version works except 12.04.3. So perhaps the answer is to take another version.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 0):

So I downloaded 13.04 and that worked fine. So the problem is 12.04.3 which I have to say is pretty poor. Perhaps it is my PC - a thinkpad so hardly a noname machine - but not impressed. Especially as others have raised this too.