# Having trouble installing any form of Ubuntu onto my fresh AMD build. Via USB

Tags: system-installation

Title says it all, I initially tried manually installing, then used `lili` and then the `exe` recommended by Ubuntu getting an array of error's. Basically need someone with experience too walk me through. This is my first time installing a Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

When using Lili, let Lili download the appropriate image for Ubuntu and then post any errors you encounter. Maybe someone can help you from there.

Comment: Done that with all the programs i've used, also tried swapping between the i386 and amd64 iso's too see if it made a difference getting the error "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Comment: Does that error show up when you are using Lili or when you are trying to install ubuntu? Maybe you could try some of the proposed solutions for [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing).