# Unable to install Ubuntu on Toshiba M50D-A-103, AMD A6-5200

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my new Toshiba notebook but cannot get past the first steps of booting. I try to install 13.10 (64-bit) from USB, the result is always the same: I get to the black screen letting me choose to try or install ubuntu (which, as I read, tells me I am in UEFI mode, which I should be, since there is already Windows 8 installed). However, booting always stops after a few lines and I get a black screen with nothing happening anymore. Everything happens very fast and I can't even read the last lines before the screen goes black.

I have tried to change the boot options, removing `quiet splash` and adding `nomodeset acpi=off nolapic no splash` (according to some suggestions I found googling). In that way I can at least read the last messages before the booting stops:

```
ata1.00:  QC timeout (cmd 0xec) 
ata1.00:   failed to identify (I/O error, ERR_mask=0x4)
ata1: limiting SATA link speed to1.5 Gbps
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
```

Then after a delay Busybox starts and I get the message:

```
(Initramfs) Unable to find medium containing a live file system
```

I am quite desperate already and would appreciate any suggestions on what this could relate to and how to solve it.

Comment: Please refer to answer of this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing). It might help.

Comment: Thank you! Using the third USB port and the above boot options I was able to install! Unfortunately other problems followed and I'm not yet able to get into the graphical interface. Normal boot stops  at a black screen with one blinking underscore. Starting in recovery mode and trying "failsafe graphic mode" gives me "Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found" -- probably however, I should mark this question as "solved" somehow and start a new thread for that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem reading from the filesystem on the USB stick. I don't know what exactly is be the cause. I had a laptop from a friend where I encountered the same problem. I then tried with a CD and that worked.

Sorry for not providinig a real explanation. But give the CD a try.

kind regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this would probably also have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Ubuntu on a Toshiba laptop, first as the sole OS, erasing Windows, and then reinstalling Windows with Ubuntu as a dual boot. Everything gave me the same black screen with the Toshiba logo. Finally, I went into the BIOS and disabled the Secure Boot, which turns out to block everything that is not Toshiba manufactured. After that, I installed Windows and Ubuntu side by side, and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: You need to provide good descriptive answer than this.