# Ubuntu install freezes using every method on Windows XP

Tags: windows, system-installation, 32-bit, windows-xp

I'll list the information I know, but I'm not a programmer or computer wizard so if you need more please explain how I can obtain it for you.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Sony Vaio laptop, running an Intel Centrino 1.73mhz processor with 502MB RAM. I've now tried every method I know of and none of them work. Here's what happens:

- From USB: I couldn't figure out how to get the computer to boot from USB so I couldn't even try that one.
- From DVD: The computer boots the disc and I can access the menu fine. However after selecting either 'install' or 'try without installing', it freezes after 10-30seconds of the red dot loading sequence. Never gets past that, just stops and remains like that until I hold the power button down and restart the computer. I performed both a CD and memory check and both passed without problems.
- From UNetbootin: I access the menu, select 'install' and it doesn't freeze on the red dot sequence but rather comes up afterwards with a command style interface and the message: "(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system" then remains like that. Again, I manually shut the computer down.
- From Wubi: I downloaded Wubi and went through the installation process so that in my Add/Remove programs list on Windows, Ubuntu is now listed as 30,000MB and installed. However every time I choose Ubuntu for it to complete the installation process, it simply gets stuck on the red dots.

I just want to install Ubuntu and would really appreciate any help, keeping in mind I'm not familiar with code and programming. I'm attempting to install the 32-bit desktop version.

Comment: With the USB one, when the computer starts, look for Boot Device selection. Select the one referencing to your USB. If that does not work, try BIOS settings, and placing USB booting as the top of the list of Boot Order. Wubi + Windows XP might not be a good idea, as Wubi [is now becoming unsupported](http://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/rip-wubi-is-this-popular-linux-into-windows-installer-destined-for-death/1883), and it relies on Windows XP, which itself [will go in April](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/end-support-help). Try a different disk image, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks wilf. I can't figure out how to get to BIOS settings though! When you suggest trying a different disk image, do you just mean I should download the .iso file again from Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, as might be that particular one had problems - there is a guide on verifying images [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Verifying_the_ISO_integrity).

Comment: Ok, I verified the .iso file and the check sums are the same. Could you give me any tips on accessing BIOS settings? Thanks again.

Comment: Press F2, F12, Enter *(it varies by manufacturer)*, then navigate to `Boot` settings. Try and place the USB device at the top of the list - it has to be plugged in before powering up. If the list is not there, or greyed out, exit and reboot, and then look for 'Boot Device Selection' again. *Honestly, why can't anyone write a guide to this...*

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 2):

With the USB one, when the computer starts, look for Boot Device selection. Select the one referencing to your USB. It may look something like:
[image]

If that does not work, try BIOS `Boot` settings, and placing USB booting as the top of the list of Boot Order.

Wubi + Windows XP might not be a good idea, as Wubi [is now becoming unsupported](http://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/rip-wubi-is-this-popular-linux-into-windows-installer-destined-for-death/1883), and it relies on Windows XP, which itself [will go in April](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/end-support-help). Try a different disk image, and see if that works.

It my  be that the disc image you are using is incomplete or faulty, so try downloading a fresh image, and [verifying it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Downloading_an_Ubuntu_ISO). There is also a guide for doing it on Windows [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I've since progressed and am onto other problems so will ask a new question and hope for the best.