# (Initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system BASIC Q

Tags: system-installation

Very new to Ubuntu & not linux savvy. I have the same 'unable to find a live medium...' issue as noted here "http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185752" [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185752).

I was trying to install on a 2 year old Dell Inspiron 1545. Background - got a new machine, the Dell was slow and Windows would frequently give me a smart drive warning. I figured it was time to wipe off Windows and go with Ubuntu as a web browser. Currently, I'm checking the disk and doing a system restore for Windows first on that old machine (it's taking a few hours).

Meantime, I want to check the DVD I burned(using the other, new machine-Windows 8, blech). However, I'm so new to this I'm lost even with MD5SUM. I was unable to check the burned DVD from the command prompt. I'd type cd D:\ and the screen would show "d:\" and then take me back to the command prompt.

So, um, HELP!

Comment: re: backgroound If you are getting frequent errors regarding smart, your drive is failing. Replace it before doing anything else or you are just wasting your time. It would be typical to check the md5sum of the iso prior to burning to disk. This may be your source of confusion. This may also help: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/command-prompt-windows-8.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score -1):

If you select the burn and verify found in most if not all burners, it will do this for you. Although, from experience, i can tell you that this is not the be all end all. Some burners suck, or are just failing.

There is a better option IMO.

If you have one availible, you can make a live flash drive to boot to.

You will need:

1. USB drive with space >2 GB
2. USB legacy support enabled on your bios. [source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19518313.aspx)
3. Ubuntu ISO
4. [universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

This skips the CD burning, and all of the headaches it can give. Plus, it is most likely faster all around.