# Problem in installing Ubuntu on Toshiba Satellite laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop and I have tried to download Xubuntu on it using a software that gives you a virtual flash disk .. because I didn't have one ..

After that, I followed the steps of installing .. . the computer was restarted / I shut it down and turned it on again. It showed the installation of xubuntu stopped, showing me a message that says,

> unable to find a medium containing a live file system

I the tried to get the xubuntu ISO file on a DVD disc and tried to install again; this resulted in the same error message.
I tried to insert a flash disc containing the ISO file and got the same message.

Why do you think this thing is happening?

Plus, how could I go into the BIOS menu and choose to boot from Windows 7, which is already on the computer, before trying to install Ubuntu?
Someone told me  how could I reach the BIOS to boot from the Windows OS that I have and fix the things using it. Or tell me how I can install Xubuntu in a right way, because I am stuck.

Important info that might **help** you find out: I downloaded the older 32-bit version of the Ubuntu ISO even though I have a newer machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Answer (score 0):

F2 or Esc will work to load Bios.
In bios check if HDD is listed.
You don't select windows load options from Bios, you only choose which hard drive to boot first. When the hard drive is loading file system it gives you option to choose the OS from available OS.

HTH

Comment: well.. I tried to use F2 and ESC before but .. the computer showed me a screen showed an interface of installing the ubutnu ??

Comment: like It didn't take me the BOIS @Uttam baroi

Comment: Often pressing F12 or F9 during boot will give you a list of devices to boot from.  Pay attention to the text on the screen as your computer boots because this will often tell you which keys to press to get boot options or enter the BIOS configuration.

Comment: Which computer model is that ?

Comment: Toshipa sattelite .. thats all I know . I don't have  info but this

Comment: If you enabled Fast Boot, you have to keep the F12 key pressed WHILE pressing the power button.

Comment: so that works even when you have a non complete installation of ubuntu ?

Comment: Okay, try Del or F10

Comment: Try Del or F10.

Comment: I am trying all of thoese thank you .. but I want to know if going to bois is possible or non possible ?

Comment: now I will go trying all of thoese keys

Comment: lets I say I got into windows .. I can delete the ubutnu data without issues?

Comment: like to back to the days of windows .. no ubutnu .. because its hard to be installed

Comment: Try to install ext2fsd on windows. It will detect your ext3, ext4 drives of Ubuntu You can download it from http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16

Comment: no it's not hard, you create another partition for that or install on virtual machine.

Comment: For detailed information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I listen got into the HDD .. but the it opened linux installation .. is that because I am on virtual machine ?

Comment: i MEAN I installed linux using virtual flash disk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I wanted to install Kubuntu. I solved it like this:

- Download Lubuntu (uses LXDE instead of XFCE/KDE/...)
- Install Lubuntu
- After installation finished and rebooted:
- Switch to TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
- Login and switch to root user: `sudo -i`
- Stop the Xserver (as a precaution); `service lightdm stop`
- Remove LXDE desktop: `apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop`
- Install XFCE desktop: `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`
- Start LightDM (Xserver) again: `service lightdm start`

If everything works fine, install updates and reboot.
If it doesn't, you'll be left without any GUI, but still able to use Windows 7 and try again...

I don't know why Lubuntu was installable and Kubuntu not, but it's working fine for me.

Comment: is that (( lubuntu)) could be installed using (( x)) one .. or its totally different thing ?

Comment: I don't get the meaning of what you're asking...