# Getting Errors when I try to install Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation

I have a notebook with these specs:

1. HP Pavilion dm1 Notebook
2. AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) Graphics 1.65 GHz
3. 4.00 GB RAM
4. 32 bit Operating System

I cannot get Lubuntu to install. I have installed the ISO to the USB drive and changed the BIOS to lauch from USB but I am still getting the following message:

```
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
```

How can I install Lubuntu?

Comment: It seems the install of the iso to your usb drive failed or wasn't done correctly. How did you put the iso on there?

Comment: just downloaded it direct from the lubuntu site

Comment: yes but how did you install the downloaded .iso file to your usb stick? Or did you just drag&drop it using your filemanager?

Comment: oh sorry.....i downloaded it directly to the usb. is there another step i should be doing after i download the iso image (i also have virtual clone drive installed on the netbook

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Comment: Instead of copying the ISO directly to USB, try extracting it to USB. Use 7Zip for extraction. Alternatively use Rufus, Etcher, Universal, dd, Startup Disk Creator, mkusb, Ventoy, Disks, etc to make a Live USB installer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using windows?

Just follow these three simple steps in order to install the iso to your stick and make it bootable: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

If you are on any Ubuntu derivative open a terminal and type `usb-creator-gtk` and follow this guide from 'Step 4' onward: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Or if you're on apples OS X follow this guide:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope no joy. So let me tell you what i am doing....
1) Plugging in a 32GB USB Pen into the netbook
2) Going to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and downloading 12.04 to my desktop
3) Downloading Universal USB Installer here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
4) Selecting Ubuntu, then the the iso image i downloaded and then the USB Drive
5) Hit create and then get an error saying "An Error occured while executing syslinux

Comment: ...mhm this may seem stupid but do you have maybe a smaller usb stick? Like 4 or 8GB? I have in the past experienced issues with these installer tools as well and it seemed to get better after I just started using my tiny 4GB usb drive

Comment: Yea I have an 8GB one....i can give that a go and see how it goes

Comment: Yea no error...I used an 8GB key and it worked.....so next problem is when i boot it just goes to the normal windows OS load.

I have changed my BIO to load USB then CD ROM and then Notebook HDrive....I also enabled USB Floppy but still no joy......any ideas

Comment: Is there a way to directly choose boot device while starting? In bios this option would be named something like `bootmenu: enabled` and on most machines pressing F12 right after startup then brings up the bootmenu

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ur notebook have "fast boot" option like my samsung laptop. try to disable it.

Comment: Having no luck at all..... Now I'm getting an input/output error when trying to do the install. It gets so far and then gets the error......