# Ubuntu 20.04 installation fails due to "Unable to find a medium container a live file system"

Tags: boot, 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 into my workstation. It has Windows 10 installed already.
The error I get is:

```
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
.
.
.
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?
yes no (default yes)
```

I used several USB sticks each ended up here. At first it shows ubuntu loading screen then this command line ui shows up and enter into initframs.

### GRUB menu terminal files

```
grub> ls
(memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt1) (hd3) (hd3,gpt4) (hd3,gpt3) (hd3,gpt2) (hd3,gpt1)
grub> ls -la
Device memdisk: Filesystem type squash4 - Last modification time 2023-01-30 10:51:57 Monday - Sector size 512B - Total size 832KiB
Device hd0: error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tar.mod' not found.
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sfs.mod' not found.
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/nilfs2.mod' not found.
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix.mod' not found.
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/afs.mod' not found.
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/affs.mod' not found.
No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 60572672KiB
    Partition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'UBUNTU 20_0', UUID 13EC-1038 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 60571648KiB
Device hd1: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 7819264KiB
    Partition hd1,msdos1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'UBUNTU 20_0', UUID 72E0-4C3A - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 7818240KiB
Device hd2: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 4000786776KiB
    Partition hd2,gpt1: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 17KiB - Total size 13367KiB
Device hd3: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 4000786776KiB
    Partition hd3,gpt4: Filesystem type ntfs, UUID DCA6D494A6D4708E - Partition start at 4000263468KiB - Total size 522240KiB
    Partition hd3,gpt3: Filesystem type ntfs, UUID ACBA4A77BA4A3E58 - Partition start at 119808KiB - Total size 4000142695.5KiB
    Partition hd3,gpt2: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 103424KiB - Total size 16324KiB
    Partition hd3,gpt1: Filesystem type fat, UUID BA46-4899 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 102400KiB
grub> ls (hd1)/
error: unknown filesystem.
```

These are the disks and filesystems in the workstation.

Comment: Does it actually say "containing"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble No, it says "container"

Comment: They must have changed it. https://askubuntu.com/q/451662/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have tried the suggestion in the post. But it did not work.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I added further information about the file system.