# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Sony VAIO T-Series laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8, vaio, gpt

I have a Sony VAIO T-Series (SVT15117CDS) laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 8. After having the computer for a while, I updated it to Windows 8.1. I now want to put Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto the computer *alongside* Windows 8.1. I want to have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / Windows 8.1 dual-boot system.

When I try to install Ubuntu in UEFI Boot Mode I get the following error after staring at the Ubuntu loading screen for over a minute:

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) build-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I am using UNetbootin to set up my USB key with the proper files.

I run into the same problem as above when I try it with Secure Boot enabled and disabled. When I try booting in Legacy Mode, I simply get a black screen saying "No operating system found".

The user in this forum topic seems to have the exact same issue as me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108810
However, I was unable to make sense of how they resolved the problem.

The volumes on the disk are set up using the GPT partition style. Here is a screenshot of my disks:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to get Ubuntu working on this laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

Comment: Also see [Installing Ubuntu-on a pre-installed Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Wow, this worked! I unplugged my USB mouse and plugged the USB key into my USB 3.0 port (it was in a USB 2.0 port before) and I was able to run the installer without problems. It first booted into a GRUB menu and from there I went to install Ubuntu.

Comment: After the install, I tried booting into Windows from the GRUB menu and I got an error. So I went back into Ubuntu and ran boot-repair. Now the computer boots straight into Windows 8. How could I fix this?

Comment: I got this working soon after I posted my last comment - I had to set some option within Windows 8, but I don't remember. Ca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plugged the USB key containing the Ubuntu install files into my USB 3.0 port (it was in a USB 2.0 port before) and I was able to run the installer without problems. It first booted into a GRUB menu and from there I went to install Ubuntu.

It seems there is a problem with the USB 2.0 ports when running Ubuntu on this laptop. See [USB 2.0 ports don't work on Sony VAIO S series laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474186/usb-2-0-ports-dont-work-on-sony-vaio-s-series-laptop).