# USB 2.0 ports don't work on Sony VAIO S series laptop

Tags: usb, 14.04, vaio, sony

I have a Sony VAIO S-series laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My USB 3.0 port works but my two USB 2.0 ports do not work.

I've read through [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138252) but could not find a solution to my problem. All USB ports work just fine in Windows 8 (I have this laptop set up to dual boot Win8 and Ubuntu) but in Ubuntu, the two USB 2.0 ports don't even seem to charge my iPod when I connect it.

What can I do to fix this problem?