# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 on UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation, uefi

I just built a new computer last week, and this weekend I got around to attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it besides Windows 7. This is my first experience really using UEFI, so I was a little surprised that the install process didn't just work for me. No matter what I did, I always ended up with a prompt saying

> Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

and I was unable to type anything, though that may be due to my wireless keyboard (wired is on the way). This prompt always comes  up after sitting at the Ubuntu loading screen for about ~2-3 minutes.

I made sure the ISO I downloaded was fine by checking the MD5Sum. Rebuilt the bootable usb (using UNetbootin) twice, no luck. The only thing I was not able to do was turn off secure boot, because I was not able to find the option on my motherboad (Gigabyte 970A-UD3P). I'm not even sure if that's a UEFI feature, or if it's just a Windows 8 feature.

I have verified that I am indeed using USB2.0 ports, and not USB3.0. I am rather lost and not sure how to proceed at this point. Any more guidance would be greatly appreciated! I really despise developing on Windows -_-

**EDIT:** more attempts:
Ok, I have tried this some more. I have now used Rufus, LiveLinux USB Creator, and Universal USB Installer. None of these have done it either. I have bought a brand new flash drive, that didn't work. Every single time it is the same story. Ubuntu loading screen for about 2 minutes, then kicked into an ash console with the message of "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". I'm not even able to type at all at this point, so I can't really get any more information. This is incredibly frustrating. I have never had this much trouble getting Linux installed before.

**HARDWARE**:

Gigabyte 970A-UD3P

AMD FX8350

GTX 760

Skill Ripjaw 2x4GB RAM

1TB HDD

Comment: Secure boot is broken anyway, you can disable it if there's such option in BIOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a different model Gigabyte mother board this may also apply.

Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3 with I7-3820
Needed F6 to set ACPI=Off.and nomodeset

Gigabyte UEFI boot issues - The partition size of the created USB Installer device needs to be under that of 4GB. 
Others found UEFI/BIOS update solved issue of 4GB FAT limit.

turns out the IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to Gigabyte boards.

Some more related info:
IOMMU for USB3 ports Gigabyte board

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370

Linux kernel enable the IOMMU – input / output memory management unit support - AMD

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-turn-on-linux-software-iommu-support.html

Comment: IOMMU was my issue. Still not sure why that affects USB ports.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use unetbootin. My experience with it is limited, but the last I heard, its support for EFI-mode booting was poor or non-existent. In my experience, the most reliable way to create an EFI-bootable USB flash drive of an Ubuntu installer is to use `dd` in Linux, or a port of `dd` to Windows or whatever other OS you can use:

```
sudo dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Change the `if=` and `of=` options as appropriate.

If you're using Windows, my limited experience with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) has also been positive.

For more on EFI-mode installs generally, see [my Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi) or the [Ubuntu community wiki.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) Both provide accurate information. Much of the advice on the Internet about EFI-mode installs is misguided.

Comment: I'll give `dd` a try. I have Ubuntu on my laptop I can use it on. I was never able to find any other software _besides_ Unetbootin on Windows to create a bootable USB.

Comment: I have tried this, and more to no avail. Updating question.

Comment: I think it was a Intel based board, but users have posted these as issues. Needed F6 to set ACPI=Off.and nomodeset
Gigabyte UEFI boot issues - The partition size of the created USB Installer device needs to be under that of 4GB. 
Others found UEFI/BIOS update solved issue of 4GB FAT limit.
turns out the IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to Gigabyte boards.

Comment: Wow turning on IOMMU did it. I have absolutely no idea why though. I don't see why IOMMU is even relevant to this

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit if you have Ubuntu on a laptop, you could use the Startup Disk Creator on it. Or Universal USB Installer on Windows.

Comment: @oldfred apparently it was the correct answer, so please post it as answer.

@ ResidentBiscuit once it's posted as answer, please mark it as accepted.

Thank you both for improving this site :)

Answer (score 1):

First decide which *firmware interface* to be used **EFI** or **Legacy mode** . [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) will help you to decide.
For uefi + Windows 8 see @Luis Alvarado's answer at [installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).
If you can't boot try the following.

- Use legacy mode (no uefi)
- Use USB 2.0 port (no USB 3)
- Remove all unwanted devices (USB, memory card)
- Disable QuickBoot/FastBoot from Windows
- Try UHCI or OHCI Host Controller (no  xHCI)

For error

> Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

As you get this error after loading the boot-loader you can load the operating system to RAM but edit and adding `toram` option to the kernel. For this , after loading boot-loader, press any arrow key to pause add option `toram` to the line that load kernel. For example `linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper`  will become `linux /casper/vmlinuz toram boot=casper` .

Answer (score 0):

Try Pen Drive Linux's USB installer as [the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) explains.

And for installing Ubuntu I recommend following the procedures noted [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) which includes:

- creating a partition for `/boot`;
- selecting the `/boot` partition as the boot loader;
- installing Ubuntu;
- making a boot item using EasyBCD on Windows.

Comment: Please read up on what UEFI is. You can install more than one bootloader on an ESP and don't need to rely on chainloading quirks like EasyBCD.

Comment: :) But I couldn't. This was what I could do with success.