# Unable to install Ubuntu server LTS via USB drive

Tags: boot, usb-drive

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exb9L.jpg

Errors received shown above. I'm not exactly sure what they mean or if they can actually be fixed (is a hardware problem a real possibility?) So far I have:

1. Reset CMOS
2. Tried every USB port on my mobo
3. Reinstalled iso on thumbdrive multiple times
4. Disabled USB 3.0 in BIOS
5. Installed ubuntu on a different computer and moved the drive to this one. This did work and ubuntu technically ran but there were other errors that I couldn't seem to fix (for starters eth0 wouldn't show up)

Potential solution (that I will try tomorrow):

After further research, it seems that there is a quirk with Gigabyte motherboards. I will use a 4gb partition and enable IOMMU as highlighted here: [Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487709/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-with-windows-7-on-uefi/489691#489691)

If this solution fixes my issue I'll delete this question tomorrow.