# Lenovo y40 will not allow me to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, lenovo

I have a Lenovo y40.

- intel i7
- 8gb memory
- 250 ssd hardrive
- AMD Radeon R9 M275 grapchis card
- windows 8.1 upgraded to windows 10 (did a fresh install)

I've tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 from USB, setup on pendrive and I also tried rufus. I've read similar questions and have tried all the answers. turned of secure boot, tried legacy mode in bios, etc ... followed different guides to the T. I haven't disabled SRT, but there seems to be no option for it in the Lenovo BIOS.

Here is what happens: I boot up the usb,  I have the option to try or install. I've tried both with the same results. Ubuntu loading screen comes on, and then after 30 seconds or so, it gives me this error: (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

I've tried it on another pc and it all works fine.

Comment: Hi, the error you are getting, for initramfs (initial ram file system), when does it appear exactly?
Can you please try a different USB port on your laptop?
This is very similar to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503783/trouble-installing-ubuntu-14-04-initramfs

Comment: "Advanced Bios Features > Installer OS Select > Windows / *Other*" Do you have a setting like here in your BIOS menu?

Comment: It appears when I click on try Ubuntu, or install Ubuntu, and immediately after the Ubuntu purple loading screen comes up, then the error. I've 3 usb options, 2 of them are 3.0 and one is 2.0 and I've tried them all.

Comment: @al0s  Yes there is something similar. It's OS Optimized Defaults, and it allows you to select other OS. I've tried this and it didn't work. But I'll try it again at your suggestion to double check. Thanks.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't think that my question is a duplicate of that question. At no point do I get a black screen, except one with the error message: (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Answer (score 0):

Please just check here:

In Settings -> Integrated Peripherials -> Sata Configuration -> Sata Mode 
(Or something like that)

Maybe, It is in IDE in your case or RAID by default. If it is like that just change it to AHCI.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1332782&page=3

Comment: The settings you are Referring to do not seem to be in the BIOS. There is actually no option in the BIOS for changing form IDE to AHCI either, unless I'm mistaken. I will triple check, but I'm pretty sure they are not there.

Comment: confirmed. no option to view the current sata mode or to set it.