# Why does the Ubutu 14.04.1 Desktop AMD64 tell me "(initramds) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"?

Tags: boot, live-environment

I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto new built PC without an OS. I burned Ubuntu 14.04.1 Desktop AMD64 onto a disc and inserted that into the disk drive and set the boot priority to the disk drive first.

Now I will go through the boot process second by second for diagnostic purposes.

0 - 15: This: [image]

15 - 40: Purple square at top left of screen with black background.

40 - 100: Ubuntu loading screen: [image]

100 - indefinate: There's a purple square at the top left corner of the screen with a £ inside it. Underneath that, it says:

```
BusyBox v1.12.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Comment: Do you use a DVD or USB?

Comment: I'm using a DVD.

Comment: Try putting the ISO on an empty USB stick (at least 2GB) using http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The provided information are not sufficient for troubleshooting. Note that there is an issue on some Gigabyte mainboards with the IOMMU. **vote to close**

possible duplicate of ["unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)