# “unable to find a medium containing a live file system” while installing using wubi?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 using wubi from windows 7 and I am getting this error “unable to find a medium containing a live file system”

[video of the problem](http://youtu.be/m4HMXXwOR20)

#### Edit

md5sum ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso is

```
1b305d585b1918f297164add46784116
```

it matches the [Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

if I use bootable USB and try it with installing `alongside with windows7` it just keep restarting from that point  and I don't want to choose the `something else` option it looks scary (might wipe out data)

Comment: did you checksum the ubuntu iso?

Comment: Yes I did just now and its matching

Comment: you install on same hdd or some pendrive?

Comment: same hdd using .iso to mount on windows 7 and installing using wubi and then reboot but it gives the error mentioned above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Comment: Wubi is no longer supported.

Comment: This can be a I/O problem with you USB stick, try reinstall with the Ubuntu ISO "burned" on a Fat32 USB stick (slow format pls) , use Yumi and post your results.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different USB stick, or try your luck re-writing it - this is clearly finding the stick & starting the boot process, but getting read errors part way through.. the medium is in some way corrupted.

Comment: if I use usb and try it with installing `alongside with windows7` it just restart from that point and I don't want to choose the `something else` option it looks scary (might wipe out my work data)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post was opened a year ago, but I'm going to post the solution I've found now to help some people who have the same problem from now.

I've been reading about it because I had the same problem when trying to load 64 bit linux mint OS from an USB stick and it seems that it happens with Gigabyte motherboards...

I found the solution here:
http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2367766

Configure your BIOS with the following parameters:

xHCI handoff - Enabled

EHCI handoff - Enabled

IOMMU controller - Enabled

Regards.