# Error Installing Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I used **Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.0** on a **lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386**, for my Toshiba Satelite (Windows 7, 2GB RAM, i3-2330m, 2.20 GHz), and when I boot it, it says:

```
[5.3011431 ACPI PCC probe failed.

starting version 219

error opening USB device 'descriptors' file

---

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-9ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

--- 

(initramfs)Unable to find a medium containing a live file system. 

(initramfs)
```

What does this mean, and what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for the possible duplicate, but so far, none of the answers helped. Still looking around then. At least I know it's not just Lubuntu.

Comment: Found my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Had to make a DVD of the thing

Comment: If this answers your question, then please write it as an answer for everyone else