# I'm not being able to install Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I'm currently using windows 10 on my PC and, for the first time in my life, I decided to go for Ubuntu and uninstall win10. I just did create the bootable USB flash drive and then entered my BIOS to change the boot order. As soon as it restarted, now booting up from the flash drive, I got a black screen with 4 options:

1. try Ubuntu
2. install Ubuntu
3. install Ubuntu OEM
4. check disk for defects

That was the first thing that went differently from the guide on Ubuntu's official website. Anyhow, I went on install Ubuntu and then I had some errors until it finished up in a black screen with some errors on the text shown:

```
[11.175178] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.GPPO.VGA_.AFN7] Namespace lookup failure,
[11.175178] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \AFN7, AE_NOT_FOUND (20
[11.175178] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA.LCD.
[11.175178] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20170831/video-364)
[17.088437] xcci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[17.088437] xcci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host support is 127.
[17.088437] usb usb1-port6: couldn't allocate usb_device
BusyBox v1.23.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

And in this screen, my keyboard isn't being detected so I'm unable to type 'help'. I tried to go for the first option (Try Ubuntu) and I had the same error. However, I'm pretty sure I have no more than 3 USB connected to my PC, including the boot drive.

I really don't have a clue about next steps I could take to make it work... Can someone help me?

Just in case I'll list my hardware:

- CPU: Ryzen 3 2200G
- MOBO: Asus Prime a320m-c
- RAM: 8gb ddr4 ram 2133
- VGA: GTX 1050ti
- SSD: 240GB booting windows yet
- HDD: 1TB Barracuda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to insert comments (yet) but these guys here

[Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

managed to get around the live file system thing by downgrading from USB3 to USB2.

That might be the cause of your woes.

Good luck!

Comment: I did try to downgrade it, and it didn't work... I even tried to change my usb stick and it didn't work as well... Thanks anyhow :)

Comment: Bummer. I googled the motherboard and it does have a USB port that is USB3 as well as a USB port that is USB2. I assume you tried using both the ports. What a pain. NMaybe try a different distribution? Linux mint?

Comment: tried Arch Linux and Manjaro :/