# Booting from USB: initramfs, medium container

Tags: boot, usb

Apologies for the general title, but I don‘t know how more succinctly I can express the issue.

I have an HP Spectre 13-v000 laptop. It has Windows 10 installed. I want to turn it into a Linux laptop.

I followed the instructions in “installing Ubuntu desktop” (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) and “create a bootable usb stick on windows”(https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).

I prepared the usb stick (with Ubuntu 20.04), plugged in and got an: “unable to find a medium container a live file system”.

I googled, and it was suggested to change usb-port, use a usb-hub or disable usb 3.
The point is that this laptop only has usb-c ports (for normal usb there is the adapter from hp). I tried all ports to no avail. I looked around in the BIOS settings, but I don’t see any ‘disable usb3’ (as it should, as there are only usb-c’s).

I googled deeper, and I found these possibilities:

1. Enable legacy support
2. Disable secure boot
3. Change order of uefi boot (priorities usb)
4. Change order of legacy boot (priorities usb)

I tried the first 3 possibilities to no avail.

I get a screen with:

[0.528902] initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
stein: Invalid argument
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive NetBoot from a URL?
yes no (default yes):_

I am a newbie, so maybe I misunderstood something when googling: I do not want a dual system. This is a laptop which I am not using anymore. I want to learn Linux commands, and thought to completely wipe out the old Windows OS from it.

Should I change the above mentioned BIOS settings? What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)