# Ubuntu Studio 21.04 does not install

Tags: system-installation

Not having internet in my apartment, I am using the .iso on a DVD.
None of the questions and solutions regarding v21.04 installation would pertain to my problem. Here it is:

I have 3 computers. v21.04 would not install on either.

First computer:

MoBo: MSI x58A-GD45 socket 1366, XEON x580, 24 Gigs memory. Clean install (no partitions on disk).
Blue Ubuntu Studio label on bottom of screen present. After some wait on top of screen I get the
following (install doesn't even get to Live):

- Starting Set console scheme...
- A green small icon: Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen
- Failed to start Disk Manager
- Failed to start Snap Daemon
- Failed to start Wait till snapd is fully seeded

Screen blank (that is, black), but mouse present and movable. Disk light off, no activity. Checked DVD integrity; fine, no problems showed. Downloaded the .iso again and made another DVD. Checked integrity, OK. I thought that, maybe 21.04 needs the computer to have UEFI. This doesn't so I moved on to computer Nr.2. This one has BIOS+UEFI.

MoBo: MSI x570  Gaming Edge WiFi, AMD Ryzen 5, gen 3, PCIe4, 32 Gigs.

Same situation, it doesn't even get to Live after the blue label on bottom of screen. So I waited again.
This time the program started to look for all kinds of URLs and after giving up reaching them it prints  this:

"Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". The drive is a dvd/blu ray. Finally, the .iso stops, showing BASH with initrams in parentheses and a cursor blinking. It takes some commands, I was able to look into the .iso's directories, but not much more.

Then, I moved to the third computer. This one has an ASRock Fata1ity Killer board with an Intel 4790 processor, 32 Gigs and a BIOS+UEFI arrangement. The situation is a copy cat of the first computer's. Nothing comes up. Not one of the computers gets even close to Live.

Comment: It sounds like your installation media is invalid. Does it pass integrity checks?

Comment: this other answer might help : https://askubuntu.com/a/26864/1257503

Comment: If you carefully read my writing, it says that I checked the integrity of both downloads that I used to make DVD .isos. The problem may still be some config in the Bios/UEFI of all of the computers, although, as I stated, there were absolutely NO problems encountered with v20.04. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had one. I have a similar issue. I did make some progress with this tho..
https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/
however my issue now, is it boots, and installs 21.04. When I remove the dvd,it still works until it is shut down, when the original problem returns.
Been messing with it now for a week. beginning to pull out my hair.

Charlie

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185972)

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same problem here with a Fujitsu Celsius M740. Didn't find a solution either, but still had a DVD around here with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS on it. Tried to install this one and it works like a charm!
Could it have something to do with switching to KDE?
I have no idea. I'm hoping now, that a direct upgrade to 22.04 LTS in April might do the trick.