# Can't install ubuntu 20.04 from USB

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation

I wanted to download ubuntu 20.04 on my old pc, but when I tried to run it from the USB I got an error:`unable to find a medium container a live file system`.
Then it starts to ask me to attempt interactive netboot from a URL. If I say yes I have to choose methods of IP configuration and also a url where default one can't be found on the server (https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso).It would then spam about No DHCPOFFERS received.

Is there any way to fix this?

Info:
PC: HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF

Edit:

I have tried to remake live usb 5 times.
I've checked the hash of downloaded iso file.
I used Rufus to make a bootable USB with iso from releases.ubuntu.com (I have successfully did this with other iso files).
I made sure to follow all of the instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen.  Sometimes the issue itself is the USB thumb drive or the tool used to create the live USB.  I have had cheaper USB drives stop being detected by the Linux boot up process, like they will begin the bootup process but then somehow get unmounted halfway through (must be a bug).  You should be getting USB device not found errors in the terminal in that case.  Regardless, I would suggest the following:

1. Create the bootable live USB drive using Balena Etcher: https://www.balena.io/etcher/
2. Attempt to boot the USB drive
3. If you get "unable to find media container" errors, you can try to physically remove the drive and reinsert it during the bootup process to see if that gets it to be detected again.
4. If you still are getting stuck, the issue is likely the USB drive itself not playing well when used as a live USB drive.  Create a live USB using a different model drive all together.

Comment: Changing drive to my external SSD helped. Thanks!