# Install Ubuntu on HP Envy 36o laptop with Ryzen 3 2300U and radeon vega graphics

Tags: system-installation, mount, live-usb, amd-ryzen

After reading several posts and trying to get the bios to read the USB with Ubuntu 22.04 iso I found it read and failed to load. I was encouraged to read that Ubuntu 22.10 worked and I tried that without success until I followed a post about using Rufus in Windows to read and recognise the usb. A this point I was stopped at a blank screen.
Another post said "I had the same problem but was able to get the live disk to load and install by adding "acpi=off spec_store_bypass_disable" to the grub command.  Now it is working great"
This worked and using e to edit grub boot by adding that to the linux boot line and removing quiet splash I was able to see

"corrupted directory entry in block-------------" not able to read the rest

mounting /dev/sdb4 on /cdrom failed: Bad message
EXT4-fs (sdb4):VFS:Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum. Run e2fsck?

this was repeated multiple times followed by
"Unable to find  medium containing a live file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a url"
to which I answer no because there is no internet connection
this takes me to Busyboxv1.35
"(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"
I have searched the file system for a lead on how to progress but so far no ideas

Comment: The message "*Unable to find medium containing a live file system*" implies your ISO was corrupt (*did you verify it?*) OR your write of the ISO to media was *corrupted* thus the media is not detected as *valid* (why it can't be found).   Your error was shown is likely procedural; did you perform the ISO validation? and write to media as is documented using correct version(s) of apps?  Use another system to verify the media if needed (*it's what I do if one box fails to boot it, so I can rule out bad write of ISO to media!*)  Other causes are too low RAM (esp. on VM) etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

Comment: I created a new usb iso of 22.04 which booted and ran. I installed this on the hard drive and towards completion gave the message "not able to install grub, install failed." The laptop then booted to grub prompt but I could not load Ubuntu. I downloaded boot-repair and ran it. First time it said no grub installed but failed to fix it. I ran it again with an internet connection and it fixed the problem. Ubuntu 22.04 now works on this laptop.